# Remove duplicates trigger Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

if I insert more than one line with the same cod_regista, it creates duplicates, how can I eliminate them? 
I only need one record per value

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER piazzetta_trg
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON regia_piazzetta
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF INSERTING THEN
     FOR a IN(SELECT cod_regista, SUM(costo_produzione) as tot
              FROM regia_piazzetta
              GROUP BY cod_regista)
        LOOP     
            INSERT INTO piazzetta_tot VALUES (a.cod_regista, a.tot);
        END LOOP;
    UPDATE piazzetta_tot SET costo_totale = costo_totale + :new.costo_produzione WHERE piazzetta_tot.id_regista = :new.cod_regista;
END IF;
IF UPDATING THEN 
    UPDATE piazzetta_tot SET costo_totale = costo_totale+(:new.costo_produzione - :old.costo_produzione) WHERE piazzetta_tot.id_regista = :new.cod_regista;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Not exacty sure what you are trying to accomplish, but your code looks wrong. Whenever you insert a `regia_piazetta`, you try to create `piazetta_tot` rows for all distinct `cod_regista`, even for those not at all used in the insert statement. Maybe a (materialized) view would better fit your requirements.

Comment: Can I use LIMIT clause for delete instruction in trigger?

Comment: A row-level trigger can't query the table that it's defined on.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use a trigger. Create

- primary key, or
- unique key (allows nulls), or
- unique index

and let the database take care about *duplicates*.

Alternatively, handle the issue while inserting rows into a table, in `INSERT` statement. Trigger should be your last choice.